# reStructuredText in Sphinx and Docstrings: single vs. double back-quotes or back-ticks difference

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docstring

From the documentation, it appears that the double back-quote is used for
literals, while the single back-quote is used when there is code text to be intepreted.

This would lead me to to write the docstring for method  `f()` below:

```
class A(B):

    def f(arg1, arg2):
        return B(arg1 + arg2 + self.index)
```

As:

```
Takes two arguments, ``arg1` and ``arg2``, which are assumed to be objects
of type (or duck-type) `NiceClass`, and returns a new object of class `B`
with `B.something` assigned some hash of ``arg1`` and ``arg2``.
```

Would this be correct?

In many code examples, Sphinx and otherwise, I see the equivalent of `B` and `NiceClass` wrapped in double back-quotes ("``B``" and "``NiceClass``").

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html):

> The default role (`content`) has no special meaning by default. You are free to use it for anything you like, e.g. variable names; use the `default_role` config value to set it to a known role.

As a matter of personal preference, when writing Python docstrings, I use interpreted text (single backquotes) for Python names and dotted paths, whether or not they are in scope at the location of the docstring. So in your case I would put `arg1`, `arg2`, `NiceClass`, `B` and `B.something` all in single backquotes, optionally adding the appropriate `:class:`, `:mod:` etc. roles.

Answer (score 23):

Just a reminder, not to be confused with Markdown's backtick string for inline code span.

In Markdown, according to the [CommonMark Spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#code-spans), these are equivalent:

- Plain text view --> Render results
- `` `inline literal` `` --> `inline literal`
- ``` ``inline literal`` ``` --> `inline literal`
- ```` ```inline literal``` ```` --> `inline literal`
- ...

  This is because they are all seen as the [backtick string](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#backtick-string):

  > A backtick string is a string of **one or more** backtick characters (`) that is neither preceded nor followed by a backtick.

---

While in reStructuredText, single backtick surround and double backticks surround
[are different](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#inline-markup):

- `` `interpreted text` `` --> the render result is depended on different definitions.

  > The rendering and meaning of interpreted text is domain- or
  >   application-dependent. It can be used for things like index entries
  >   or explicit descriptive markup (like program identifiers).
- ``` ``inline literal`` ``` --> `inline literal`

  > Normally rendered as monospaced text. Spaces should be preserved, but line breaks will not be.

So in general, reStructuredText's double backticks surround ``` ``code`` ``` is somewhat equivalent to Markdown's single backtick surround  `` `code` ``.